# Using the TYPE command inside a Redis / Lua Script

Tags: lua, redis

I am attempting to use the Redis [TYPE](http://redis.io/commands/type) command inside a Lua script (executed via EVAL)

```
local key_type = redis.call("TYPE", key)
```

According to the Redis documentation, this should return a string of `"none"`, `"zset"` etc.

However the type of the returned value is a lua `table`. Comparing the value to a string always returns false.

I've managed to get around the problem by changing the call to

```
local key_type = redis.call("TYPE", key)["ok"]
```

This value is indeed a string and does work in string comparison commands. I am worried that this is a bug in my particular version of Redis and it will break in future versions when I upgrade.

Does anyone know if this is expected behaviour, or a bug?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The [`TYPE`](http://redis.io/commands/type) command returns a *status reply* (a.k.a simple string), e.g  `"+list\r\n"`.

On Redis scripting side, `call` is implemented by [`luaRedisCallCommand`](https://github.com/antirez/redis/blob/4beaaff/src/scripting.c#L349-L351) which performs the real Redis command behind the scenes.

Once successfully executed, this function converts the command result with [`redisProtocolToLuaType`](https://github.com/antirez/redis/blob/4beaaff/src/scripting.c#L68-L89).

When a status reply is encountered, this function **creates a Lua table** with `"ok"` as key, and the status reply as value (see [`redisProtocolToLuaType_Status`](https://github.com/antirez/redis/blob/4beaaff/src/scripting.c#L114-L122)). So:

- there is no bug,
- this is why `redis.call("TYPE", key)` is a table (and thus you need to get the value for the `"ok"` key as you did, to get `key`'s type as a string).

Note: when you directly return the table, Redis takes care to get the value associated to the `"ok"` key, and returns it as a status reply, e.g:

```
> EVAL 'return redis.call("TYPE", "foo")' 
set
```

See this [code section](https://github.com/antirez/redis/blob/4beaaff/src/scripting.c#L725-L735) for more details.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed and knowledgable answer.